# How to set Gravity Form consent field to checked by default?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How do I set a gravity form consent field to checked by default?
I tried the below but no luck... Any idea?

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_1', 'my_populate_checkbox' );

function my_populate_checkbox( $form ) {
  
  foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
    
    if( 7 === $field->id ) {

      foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ) {
            
          $choice['isChecked'] = true;
        
      } 
    } 
  } 

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add javascript to your form:

```
function check_consent() {
    document.getElementById("input_1_7_1").checked = true;
}
check_consent();
```

I use a plugin called [Gravity Forms Custom Javascript](https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-custom-javascript/) by Gravity Wiz
Otherwise you can try to enqueue your own custom code:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/